# Yaml - multi line syntax without delimiter

Tags: yaml

Is it possible in Yaml to have multi-line syntax for strings without an additional character generated between newlines?

Folded (>) syntax puts spaces, literal syntax (|) puts newlines between lines.
The summary here does not give a solution: [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines).

E.g.

```
>-
  line1_
  line2
```

generates `line1<space>line2` - I would like to have `line1_line2` without additional token.

Answer (score 1):

Use a double-quoted string:

```
"line1_\
line2"
```

By escaping the newline character, it is completely removed instead of being translated into a space. It is not possible to do this with block scalars because they have no escape sequences.

Comment: good idea, but I would like to have a similar functionality to block scalars (no escaping) without the additional space / newline

Comment: Well, there is none. Quoted scalars are the only way to split a scalar at arbitrary points (i.e. not at a space or newline).